# Working with global variables in multiple classes and multiple modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, scope, global-variables

If I create a global variable in a function in a class, how can I use that variable in another function in a different class?

NB: Classes are found in different modules.

Do I need to declare the global variables in the **init** function of each class?

Answer (score 2):

Global vars can be accessed throughout the module they are declared in. To access a global variable declared in one module from within another one, simply do:

Module1.py:

```
global foo
foo = "bar"
```

Module2.py:

```
import Module1
Module1.foo
```