# I cannot get the correct value of a modified global variable (from a class) to another class in separate files

Tags: python-3.x

So, I have:

### file_1.py

```
variable_one = 20
```

and I also have:

### file_2.py

```
class class_2():
    def do_something_2(self):
        ...
        from file_1 import variable_one
        variable_one = 100
        print("variable_one = ", variable_one) # 100
        ...
```

and that:

### file_3.py

```
class class_3():
    def do_something_3(self):
        ...
        from file_2 import variable_one
        print("variable_one = ", variable_one) # 20
        ...
```

The problem is that although `file_2.py` changes the `variable_one`, in the `file_3.py` I don't get the number 100 but the number 20. `variable_one` in
`file_1.py` is defined as `global`. I have tried a recently opened thread, which works for what I asked there but the current problem is a bit different in the current thread (here: [Cannot access global variable inside a parent class (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72284690/cannot-access-global-variable-inside-a-parent-class-python/72300237#72300237)). I have also tried this suggestion: [Working with global variables in multiple classes and multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630802/working-with-global-variables-in-multiple-classes-and-multiple-modules) and I got this:

```
AttributeError: module 'class_2' has no attribute 'variable_one'
```

Any idea how to read the correct (modified global variable in file_2.py) from class_3 ???

Comment: I guess, `from class_2 import variable_one` should be `from file_2 import variable_one`?
Otherwise, with this setup, the import won't work, won't it?

Comment: I changed it! Wrong representation because the code is much larger and I give the main idea here... Thanks! So, I correct it to my question...How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why this should be useful, but here's why it doesn't work like you're trying:

`variable_one` is only set in file_2.py, if you call `class_2.do_something()`. To fix this, you have to define `variable_one` in the constructor of `class_2`.

```py
from file_1 import variable_one
class class_2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable_one = variable_one + 1
    def do_something_2(self):
        pass
```

Now `variable_one` is set, when you create an object of type `class_2`. That's why you cannot import `variable_one`, as it's not global, just in the scope of `class_2`.

If you now do the following, you should have access to `variable_one` from *file_3.py*:

```py
from file_2 import class_2
class class_3:
    def do_something_3(self):
        c2 = class_2()
        # Now prints variable_one from file_1 incremented by '1' (see file_2)
        print("variable_one =", c2.variable_one)

c3 = class_3()
c3.do_something_3()
```

Comment: I get this:     ```from file_2 import class_2
ImportError: cannot import name 'class_2' from partially initialized module 'file_2' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/user/Desktop/my_code/file_2.py)```

Comment: In **file_1.py** I have also ```from file_2 import class_2```. And maybe that's the problem, but I can't remove it, because it does not work....